# how to insert keys to objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to insert each keys from object to another object , I wanna add it to the payload.

I tried  this one but it was insert as a whole object. What I want is to get the sample result below . Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
const payload: requestPayload| any = {
          accountId: 1,
          keystoInsert
        };
```

#object that I wanna insert

```
keystoInsert = {
    "marketName": "Chicago",
    "roleUserFirstName": null,
    "roleUserLastName": null,
    "roleUserEmailAddress": null
}
```

#code snippet

```
 const payload: requestPayload | any = {
      accountId: 1,
    };
```

#expected output

```
{
    "accountId": 1,
    "marketName": "Chicago",
    "roleUserFirstName": null,
    "roleUserLastName": null,
    "roleUserEmailAddress": null
}
```

Comment: Use spread syntax `...keystoInsert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread on both objects:

```js
const payload = {
  accountId: 1,
};

const keystoInsert = {
  "marketName": "Chicago",
  "roleUserFirstName": null,
  "roleUserLastName": null,
  "roleUserEmailAddress": null
}

const output = {
  ...payload,
  ...keystoInsert
}

console.log(output)
```